# KeyCloack Admin Rest ordering paginated results

Tags: keycloak

Im using python_keycloak to call keycloak "users" rest api. Im using KeyCloak 18.

Im following this page: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/rest-api/#_users_resource

I've managed to paginate the result using MAX and FIRST attribute. Unfortunally there is NO ordering parameter.

I need to order my results, before pagination, based on a dynamic user attribute (based on the column the user is ordering by).

For example I want first 20 users ordered by lastName.

Am I missing something or the Admin Rest Api does not have any ordering parameter?

Is a post-production way the only way?

Comment: Keycloak get user list REST API not supported by sort.  It just supports filtering by last name or first name.

Comment: What a useless Rest Endpoint...